# Interior Point of $ A = \{ \frac{1}{n} : n = 1, 2, 3, ... \}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have stumbled upon this question in a text book, where one is expected to find the set of interior points of this given set in the real line with the usual metric.

I feel like this set doesn't have interior points? Because it is such that for example, not all the elements in a ball centered at, let's say, $\frac {1}{8}$ will be in the set $A$, surrounded by numbers like $ \{ \frac{1}{7.889}, \frac{1}{7.912}, \frac{1}{8.5} \}$ or whatever, which are real numbers but not necessarily in the given defined set.

So I think this set doesn't have so many interior points. Or do I not get what interior points are.

Comment: For this set, the only accumulation point is 0. The set is neither open, nor closed (with standard topology in $\mathbb{R}$). The closure of the set (in $\mathbb{R}$) is $A \cup \{ 0 \}$ and the interior (in $\mathbb{R}$) is empty. Further the boundary is exactly equal to its closure (since $\partial {A} = \bar{A} - \text{int} \ A $). Lastly all points in this set are interior points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, this set has no interior points. The definition of interior point here is: for all $x \in A$, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset A$.

The denial of this statement is: for every value of $\epsilon > 0$, $(x-\epsilon, x + \epsilon) \not\subset A$.

This indeed happens. Given $1/n \in A$, and any $\epsilon> 0$, the interval $((1/n)-\epsilon, (1/n)+\epsilon)$ contain a point not in $A$. Say, for example, an irrational number.

Comment: Thank you! I thought as much :D